# How to get css file to html in server side rendering ReactJs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I'm doing server side rendering for my React JS App.But i cannot load .css and images to html file.

My directory structure

```
build
public
 index.html
 styles.css
 fav.png
src
 client
  client.js
 index.js
webpack.js
```

my index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/fav.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my index.js file (server file)

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import Home from './client/components/MyHome';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import Transmit from 'react-transmit';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';    
import reducers from './client/reducers';    
const store = createStore(reducers)

function handleRender(req, res) {
  Transmit.renderToString(Home).then(({reactString, reactData}) => {
    fs.readFile('./public/index.html', 'utf8', function (err, data) {

      const document = data.replace(/<div id="root"><\/div>/,
      `<div id="root">${reactString}</div>`);

      res.send(document);
    });
  });
}

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('*', handleRender);
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

load css on webpack.js

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
     { fallback: 'style-loader', use: [ 'css-loader' ] }
   ) 
 }
```

Problem is when i run my app,it's not loaded css and png files.

Comment: you need appropriate loaders for that, CSS loader and url loader

Comment: install those packages and use them

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier I have loaded those packages on webpack.js file.I have updated my post.

Comment: where is your css file located? have you hosted it as a static file?

Comment: css file is inside public folder

Answer (score 0):

make this change in the html file

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: I have did this change on my file.but doesn't load css

Answer (score 0):

The way you have included the css will not work. Lets assume you have put the **style.css** file in a folder named **Styles** in the **root directory** and in the root directory you have your server entry point index.js.

you have to first host this directory as a static folder this is done by adding the following line in your index.js

```
app.use("/Styles", express.static(path.join(__dirname, './Styles')));
```

This will allow you to access the files inside this directory after hosting

you can access the file using the url

```
 http://localhost:3000/Styles/styles.css
```

Add this url to your to your html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:3000/Styles/styles.css">
```